# Django get request not calling my method for the second time

Tags: django

I am writing a simple Django backend and testing it using Postman. I have several post methods and get methods. All of the post methods work fine. The get method behaves strangely. When the get request is sent for the first time, it correctly returns the response. However when the get request is sent again, my request handling method is not called and it just returns the response last time, even if some data changed between these two calls. If I send a login request before each get request, it also works fine.

Any idea why it is like that and how can I make sure that my request handler is called every time?

This is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from myApp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.user_register, name='register'),
    url(r'^get_children_summary/$', views.get_children_summary, name='get_children_summary'),
    url(r'^get_children_info/$', views.get_children_info, name='get_children_info'),
    url(r'^add_child/$', views.add_child, name='add_child'),
    url(r'^delete_child/$', views.delete_child, name='delete_child'),
)
```

Comment: Show the code, please.

Comment: which part of the code? The method is not even called so I feel the code is not relevant

Comment: I attached my urls.py